# How to auto highlight comments in nano?

Tags: highlighting, nano

I was wondering how could I make lines commented with a `#` highlighted in a different colour in nano?

[I saw this question on askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90013/how-do-i-enable-syntax-highlighting-in-nano) that shows how to syntax highlight for different languages. However this is overkill for just highlighting comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax highlighting tends to be language specific. However, if you want to do it for all files, you can simply create a very very simple language definition. I took the Perl syntax style (which treats lines starting with `#` as comments) from `/usr/share/nano/perl.nanorc` and adapted it to:

```
syntax "All" "."
color green "^\s*#.*"
```

As far as I can tell, the nano syntax highlight format needs at least one test to define the file type, and then you can set filters for the color. So, I used the most simple test I can think of, that the file's name contains at least one character, and I named this syntax style `All`:

```
syntax "All" "."
```

I then told it to color lines starting with 0 or more spaces and then a `#` in green:

```
color green "^\s*#.*"
```

So, if you create a file called `$HOME/.nanorc` and paste those two lines into it, your comments will be highlighted in green.

Comment: When using `.nanorc` with includes to multiple language files, include this "All" first. That will make more specific configuration take precedence.